# Default images of android checkbox and edittext

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-checkbox

Where I can find images of these edittext and checkbox elements? I want to modify and replace them after in styles.xml.
[image: my layout looks like:]

Comment: You must understand more about Android UI before asking this question! It is about the background, colors and other styles.

Comment: @NguyenDoanTung so lets make it clear. It is not about images? 
I know there are checkbox/edittext images for holo light (holo dark).

Answer (score 1):

**Solution:**

In your `styles.xml`, in your theme section, add following lines:

```
<item name="colorControlNormal">#000000</item>
<item name="colorAccent">#000000</item>
```

`colorControlNormal` is for coloring component when not focused / not checked
`colorAccent` is for coloring component when focused / checked

Where `#000000` is color which you want.

This will apply to all components in application, but you can also do it for specific `CheckBox` or `EditText` only.

Then you just need to create separate theme in `styles.xml` with mentioned attributes and add to these components line:

```
android:theme="@style/MyCustomTheme"
```

**Example:**

```
<style name="MyCustomTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="colorControlNormal">#000000</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">#000000</item>
</style>
```

**Note:**

This solution is for `AppCompat` library, mostly used now.

Comment: Thanks for reply. 
And yes, my activity extends "android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity". Your solution. Will it override cyan color everywhere? What if I need to change edittext and/or checkbox only?